# Probability that a draw from one sample is greater than a draw from a another sample

Tags: r, probability

I have a sample of `b` for id=1 and I want to compare this sample with the sample of id={2,3} of `a` i.e. I want to compute the probability that a draw from sample `b` (id=1) is greater than a draw from sample `a` (id={2,3}).

```
    library(data.table)
    df <- data.table(id=c(rep(1,500),rep(2,500),rep(3,500)),a=rnorm(1500),b=rnorm(1500,1))
    ot <- df[id!=1,a]
    ow <- df[id==1,b]
    sa <- df[id!=1,sample(a,500)]
    #all permutations of eig and sam
    fall <- expand.grid(ow,sa)
    #all permutations of eig and other
    all  <- expand.grid(ow,ot)

    #1. best possible empirical measure
    sum(all[,1]>all[,2])/nrow(all)
    #2. 
    sum(fall[,1]>fall[,2])/nrow(fall)
    #3.  
    sum(ow>sa)/length(sa)
```

Nb. 1 would obviously be the best solution as in my real data set the distributional properties of a and b are unknown. Nb. 1 is however not feasible because I would have to repeat this procedure for every `ID`. My data set is huge.

The solution I used until now was Nb. 3: I a draw a random sample from `a` (id={2,3}) in the size of the sample for `b` (id=1). But this is of course imprecise. Solution Nb. 2 would be a compromise but is also not feasible computation-wise.

I would like to find a data table (this is a faster implementation of data frames in the form of the R package "data.table") solution because those are normally much faster.

I didn't post this question on Stackoverflow, because I also hoped that one of you could maybe hint me to a mathematical trick to overcome this problem, but of course also coding advises are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say you always get a bias when comparing samples from group 1 with samples from groups 3 and 10 combined?

Comment: @M.Berk I completely rewrote the question. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Can you write in plain math instead of R code?

Comment: This isn't even working `R` code! -- What is `data.table`?  There are no variables `a` or `b` to make sense of the second through fourth lines, either.

Comment: @whuber data.table is more efficient implementation of data.frame: much, much faster! i thought this standard by now.

Comment: I cannot even find `data.table` in the help system. What package is it in? But more to the point--questions that require an understanding of a particular computing language to read are not on-topic here.  Although providing (reasonably documented) `R` code is fine for illustration, it is essential that your question be stated in English and mathematical notation.

Comment: @whuber, it's a [package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html). If you can't find it, probably because the data.table package has not been evoked.

Comment: BTW, I believe there is a simple and highly efficient solution to the problem I *think* I see here.  However, I am puzzled by the business about `id`: that looks irrelevant to me.  Aren't you simply asking how to compute the chance that a random draw from one set exceeds a random draw from another (assuming there are no ties)? In your actual case, are ties possible?

Comment: @Penguin_Knight Thanks, I know how to search for packages (at http://rseek.org/ and other places). The point is that *people should not have to search the Web in order to be able to read questions here!*  If they have to, the question needs clarification.

Comment: @whuber Well the id variable stands for groups. I want to compare a sample which belongs to group 1 of var b to the sample of all other groups of var a.

Comment: Is your question about how to program `R` to iterate a calculation over groups or is it about how to compute a probability?

Comment: @whuber well both. but as i stated in the last paragraph of my question, i posted it here and not on stackoverflow because i thought there might be some maths trick which could solve my problem. i know how to code the stuff in R, but as i mention above to work with all combinations of a and b as in the example above is not feasible because my data set is too large.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**There is a simple efficient solution.**  It uses the ideas common to all rank-sum tests, such as the Wilcoxon tests.  This answer derives the solution and provides an `R` implementation.

---

The code in the question simulates data that have a vanishingly small chance of exhibiting any ties at all between a sample of group $a$ and a sample of group $b$, so **let's assume there exist no ties.**

Let there be $m$ elements in $a$ (and they *can* have ties among each other) and $n$ elements in $b$ (which also may have ties). Let $A$ be the random variable modeled by drawing one element randomly and uniformly from group $A$ and similarly let $B$ be the random variable for one draw from group $B$.  **The desired value (as I interpret the question) is the chance that $A$ exceeds $B$.**

Notice that the test of whether a realization of $A$ exceeds one of $B$ is a simple comparison. Thus, the problem is unchanged if we replace all elements of $a$ and $b$ by their *indexes* when the two sets are sorted in increasing order.  These indexes are their *ranks*, provided that ties are resolved in some arbitrary manner (that is, do *not* average the ranks of any groups of ties).

**For example,** let $a = (0,2)$ and $b = (1,1,3)$.  Sorting the combined two (multi)sets gives the sequence $(0,1,1,2,3)$.  The indexes of the values coming from $a$ are $1$ and $4$ while the indexes of the values from $b$ are $2, 3,$ and $5$.

**Compute the chance** $\Pr(A\gt B)$ by summing over the possible values of $A$, each of which has the probability $1/m$.  Let the ranks of these values be $r_1 \lt r_2 \lt \cdots \lt r_m$.  Suppose $r_i$ is picked.  Then the chance, conditional on this selection, that $B$ has a *smaller* value equals the number of smaller values in $b$ divided by $n$.  The number of smaller values *altogether* in both $a$ and $b$ is, by definition, $r_i-1$, but we know exactly $i-1$ of them (namely, $r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_{i-1}$) are in $a$.  Thus

$$\Pr(A \gt B | A = r_i) = \frac{1}{n}\left(r_i-1 - (i-1)\right) = \frac{1}{n}\left(r_i-i\right)$$

entailing

$$\Pr(A\gt B) = \sum_{i=1}^m \Pr(A\gt B | A=r_i)\Pr(A=r_i) = \frac{1}{mn}\sum_i \left(r_i-i\right).$$

**In the example,** $\Pr(A\gt B) = \frac{1}{2\times 3}((1-1) + (4-2)) = \frac{2}{6}$ and (reversing the roles of $a$ and $b$ as a quick check) $\Pr(B\gt A) = \frac{1}{3\times 2}((2-1) + (3-2) + (5-3)) = \frac{4}{6} = 1 - \frac{2}{6}$ as one would expect.

This calculation (when implemented as a general-purpose algorithm) requires sorting all $m+n$ values to find their ranks and then summing either $m$ or $n$ values (for efficiency, one would pick whichever is smaller).  Therefore the computational burden is $O((m+n)\log(m+n)),$ and can be reduced to $O(\min(m\log(n), n\log(m)))$ when the larger of $a$ and $b$ is already sorted.  That's pretty efficient.

**When there are ties** between elements of $a$ and $b$, the idea to reduce the question to rank sums and then compute a sum over conditional probabilities still works, but the calculations of the conditional probabilities get more complicated.

---

#### R Code

`R` will have trouble with calculations that overflow its integer data type.  The following solution handles that possibility.

```
prob <- function(a, b, ...) {
  # Returns chance that a random sample of `a` will exceed one of `b`
  # (assuming no ties between elements of `a` and `b`)
  # Optional args are passed to `rank` to control handling of NAs and
  # how to resolve any ties.
  m <- length(a); n <- length(b)
  if (m < n) {
    r <- rank(c(a,b), ...)[1:m] - 1:m
  } else {
    r <- rank(c(a,b), ...)[(m+1):(m+n)] - 1:n
  }
  s <- ifelse ((n+m)^2 > 2^31, sum(as.double(r)), sum(r)) / (as.double(m)*n)
  return (ifelse(m < n, s, 1-s))
}
```

To emulate the data in the question, let's simulate sets of normally distributed values.  When the elements of $a$ come from a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ and those of $b$ come from a normal distribution with mean $\nu$ and SD $\sigma$, we may analytically compute that $\Pr(A\gt B)$ (*prior* to simulating the elements) equals $\Phi(\frac{\mu-\nu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}})$ where $\Phi$ is the cumulative standard normal distribution function.  This enables us to test `prob`, as in the following:

```
set.seed(17)
m <- 10^6; n <- 10^4
mu.a <- 0; mu.b <- -2
a <- rnorm(m, mu.a)
b <- rnorm(n, mu.b)
system.time(print(prob(a,b), digits=5))
system.time(print(1 - prob(b,a), digits=5))
print(pnorm((mu.a - mu.b)/sqrt(2)), digits=5)
```

The output is

```
> system.time(print(prob(a,b), digits=5))
[1] 0.92124
   user  system elapsed 
   0.51    0.00    0.51 
> system.time(print(1 - prob(b,a), digits=5))
[1] 0.92124
   user  system elapsed 
   0.51    0.00    0.52 
> print(pnorm((mu.a - mu.b)/sqrt(2)), digits=5)
[1] 0.92135
```

It shows that the computation time does not depend on the order in which `a` and `b` are provided to `prob`.  The computation time of $1/2$ second is reasonably quick (for over one million numbers).  The close agreement of $0.92124$ and $0.92135$ is evidence in favor of the correctness of this solution.

This solution can easily be iterated over groups using the usual `R` idioms for looping.

Comment: awesome! how were you able to write such a reponse so fast after my last edit!? thank you so much!

Comment: I would have one more question: can you also extend this method to conditional probabilities like P(A>B|A>C)?

Comment: I think so, although obviously it would be more complicated.

Comment: i don't want to bother you further with my questions but could you maybe hint me to literature which could help me solving this question myself?

Comment: The literature is *vast,* because underlying these calculations is the entire field of combinatorics. You might consider asking for recommendations suitable for your interests and mathematical background. The [math.se] site could be a good place for such advice.